# Slide out label with css3 transitions

Tags: html, css

I have the following [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaHec/), this is a basic positioned label with the number and marker text:

```
<span href="#" class="part-marker">
  <a href="#" class="marker-label">1<span>&nbsp;marker text</span></a>
</span>
```

How can I get it to slide out on hover using css3 transitions? I've tried using this with no success??

Answer (score 1):

See below a simplified version- the crux here being that you cant make a transition on properties that don't scale, so where you have the element going from `display:none` t `inline-block` it simply goes from hidden to shown as there are no intermediary points. What you can do instead is use a combination of `max-width` and `overflow` as outlined below.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tebe5/)

HTML

```
<div> <a href='#'>1</a>
 <span>Label</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a {
    display:inline-block;
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    padding:0 5px;
}
div {
    position:relative;
}
div span {
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:all 1s ease-in;
}
a:hover+span {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: just one small thing : transition:max-width 1s ease-in;

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative `text-indent` too : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xalDc/

```
span { 
    text-indent:-150px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;/* triggers layout */
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    /* position:absolute ; not needed since a is already so */
    }
    &:hover {
        span {
            text-indent:0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="marker-label" text="marker text">
    1
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.marker-label {
    display:block;
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    padding:4px 8px;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    width:10px;
}
.marker-label:hover {
    width:80px;
}
.marker-label:after {
    content:attr(text);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    position:absolute;
    left:-100px;
}
.marker-label:hover:after {
    left:20px;
}
```

And here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/aqKn5/1/)**